# How to color sliced intervals of x in stat_density()?

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
tibble(x = rnorm(1000,0,1)) %>%
  mutate(breaks = cut(x, c(-Inf,-1,1,Inf))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = x, fill = breaks)) + 
  stat_density()
```

I'd like to slice a unique density plot in 3 sections corresponding to the breaks.
Instead, this code produces 3 different density plot for each subgroup.

A possibile solution is here:

https://community.rstudio.com/t/conditional-or-arbitrary-fill-in-density-plots/18094

But I'd like something less verbose that does not require a `geom_area()` and an explicit pre-computed `y`, isn't there a option within `stat_density()` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can set optional aesthetics after the statistic has been calculated with `after_stat()`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

breaks <- c(-Inf, -1, 1, Inf)

tibble(x = rnorm(1000,0,1)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = x)) + 
  stat_density(
    aes(fill = after_stat(cut(x, breaks)),
        group = after_stat(as.numeric(cut(x, breaks))))
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-11-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: How to add a color scale, in this case?

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean, it already has a colour scale by default.